# The free() function and implicit type casting from 'pointer to non-void data type' to pointer to void data type

Tags: c, pointers, casting

In the book "*C Programming: A Modern Approach*, chapter 17.4 introduced the function `free()` which has the prototype of the following form: `void free(void *ptr)`. As the author outlines several examples involving dynamic storage using `malloc()`, the following snippet of quasi-code is encountered:

```
struct node {
  int value;
  struct node *next;
};

struct node *delete_from_list(struct node *list, int n)
{
  struct node *cur, *prev;
  . 
  .    /*Will explain the relevant part of this section as it pertains to the question (bullet 3 below) */
  .
  free(cur); /* <--- my question is about this line */
}
```

The important points are:

1. there is a data type known as `struct node` that has two fields
2. there is a pointer to `struct node` named `cur`
3. in the `delete_from_list` function, `cur` will eventually get assigned some address in the heap. In particular, it will get assigned to a chunk of memory with data type `struct node`.

With those 3 points established, we can attend to my question: why does calling the function `free()` with the argument `cur` work without issue? `cur` is not of type pointer to void. I assume that means there is some type of implicit (under the hood) type casting occurring that changes `cur`'s datatype from pointer to `struct node` to pointer to void. Is that the case? If so, is there a general rule about implicit type casting of pointers as argument when it comes to functions calls?

Comment: `cur will eventually get assigned some address in the heap` If you look at the line where this happens, you'll most likely find a `malloc` call or similar. That call returns a `void *` as well, regardless of what type of data you are using it for. The malloc/free functions are about memory de/allocation, not types.

Answer (score 3):

Any object pointer type may be freely converted to or from a `void *` without a cast.

Section 6.3.2.3p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any
> object type.  A pointer to any object  type  may  be  converted  to  a
> pointer  to `void` and  back  again;  the  result  shall compare equal
> to the original pointer.

Also, the `free` function may only be passed a pointer that was returned from one of the `malloc` family of functions, and these all return a `void *`.

Comment: I guess I am unsure of how to interpret your first sentence. Consider an instance where I have the following sequence of statements: `int *ptr; int a=7; ptr=&a; *ptr=6`. With the final statement (the dereference) clearly the compiler knows that `ptr` needs to be treated as a pointer to integer (i.e. the compiler chooses NOT TO convert `ptr` to `void *`. Why? How does it know in this aforementioned instance NOT TO convert `ptr` to `void *` but in my post example (with `free`) it knows TO convert the pointer to `void *`.

Comment: @S.Cramer Since `ptr` is a pointer to an `int`, dereferencing it gives you an `int`.  when passing to `free`, the type of the parameter is `void *` which is why there is an implicit conversion to `void *`  .

Comment: ohhhhh. Got it. Thank you!